# not exists, not empty and not like in query

Tags: mongodb

How to use not exists, not empty and not like together in mongoDB query. I tried below queries

```
db.getCollection('result').find({ 'sTax': { $exists: true, $ne: '', $not:/<p/ } })
```

and

```
db.getCollection('result').find({ $and: [{ 'sTax': { $ne: '' }}, { 'sTax': { $not: /<p/ }}, { 'sTax': { $exists: true, }}, ]})
```

but both are not working

what is correct query?

Answer (score -1):

I would prefer to simply use this to go back to the previous page

```
<input action="someaction" type="button" value="BackKey" onclick="history.go(-1);"/>
```

If you want to use it through link then

```
<script>
    function goBack(){
        if(history.length === 1){
            window.location = "someurl"  //If thats the first page
        } else {
            history.back();
        }
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onClick="goBack()">click here</a>
```

Comment: in my previuos page i am calculating quantity and prodauct and submit on next page & on this page have link....but when i click on this link it is going to previous page & showing all values. but the problem is that only total value not showing.. i just want to like this [link](http://storageworx.ca/moving-supplies.php) Please see this proccess.

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the question. The question is about MongoDB, whereas the answer is about a webpage.